# How to remove empty strings from the end of a list of strings (only at the end)

Tags: python, list

i have some list of strings. I want to remove empty strings from the end of the list (i.e.  each list should end with a non empty element).

```
input
list1= ['a1','b1','c1','d1','']
list2 = ['a2','','b2','','c2','d2','']
list3 = ['a3','','b3','','','']
list4 = ['','','','','']
```

output

```
list1= ['a1','b1','c1','d1']
list2 = ['a2','','b2','','c2','d2']
list3 = ['a3','','b3']
list4 = ['']
```

if all the elements are empty strings , only one empty string should remain (eg. list4).

Comment: Should be pretty simple - any attempt from you?

Comment: hi , cannot upvote , showing `-1`, while trying to upcode, don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generator comprehension with `enumerate` and keep the first index starting from the end where there is a non-empty string. By using `next` we only need to iterate until the first non-empty string is found:

```
def trim_empty_end(l):
    last_ix = next((ix for ix, i in enumerate(l[::-1]) if i), len(l)-1)
    return l[:len(l) - last_ix]
```

---

```
trim_empty_end(['a1','b1','c1','d1',''])
# ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1']

trim_empty_end(['a2','','b2','','c2','d2',''])
# ['a2', '', 'b2', '', 'c2', 'd2']

trim_empty_end(['a3','','b3','','',''])
# ['a3', '', 'b3']

trim_empty_end(['','','','',''])
# ['']
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, it will fail for the last case `list4`.

Comment: Added a default value to the `next` method. Works now @Shijith

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `str` methods.

**Ex:**

```
list1= ['a1','b1','c1','d1','']
list2 = ['a2','','b2','','c2','d2','']
list3 = ['a3','','b3','','','']
list4 = ['','','','','']

data = [list1, list2, list3, list4]

result = ["*#*".join(i).strip("*#* ").split("*#*") for i in data]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1'],
 ['a2', '', 'b2', '', 'c2', 'd2'],
 ['a3', '', 'b3'],
 ['']]
```

Comment: what's with the downvotes here...? someone just sistematically downvoted all answers

Comment: Wrong when `list5 = ['a1','b1','c1','*','']`, it returns `['a1','b1','c1']`.

Comment: @yatu.yes.. I just saw that

Comment: @TianboJi. Probably OP has to confirm this.And also its pretty easy to create your own unique identifier....I just used `*#*` as an example

Comment: @rakesh, yes, for `['a1','b1','c1','*','']`, it returns `['a1','b1','c1']', but for me this case will not arise since i am removing `* and #` for the list using a regex , before this step. this also fails for `#`

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion

```
def remove_empty(l):
    if l[-1] != "" or len(l) <= 1:
        return l
    return remove_empty(l[:-1])

print(remove_empty(list1)) # ['a1', 'b1', 'c1', 'd1']
print(remove_empty(list2)) # ['a2', '', 'b2', '', 'c2', 'd2']
print(remove_empty(list3)) # ['a3', '', 'b3']
print(remove_empty(list4)) # ['']
```

Comment: Using recursion in Python in answer to such a simple problem seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way (in my opinion)

```py
def remove_empty_at_end(l: list):
    i = len(l) - 1
    # If you're not sure the items of l are strings, then, you can do while l[i] == ""
    while not l[i] and i > 0: 
        i -= 1

    return l[:i + 1]
```

It's simple and avoids creating countless copies of `l`

Comment: Does not work: remove_empty_at_end(['a', 'b', ''] returns ['a']

Answer (score 0):

```
def trim_empty_strings(l):
    while len(l) > 1 and l[-1] == '':
        l = l[:-1]
    return l

trim_empty_strings(['a','b','', '']
trim_empty_strings(['','',''])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ['a1','b1','c1','d1','']
list2 = ['a2','','b2','','c2','d2','']
list3 = ['a3','','b3','','','']
list4 = ['','','','','']

data = [list1, list2, list3, list4]  -->
data = [['a1','b1','c1','d1',''], ['a2','','b2','','c2','d2',''], ['a3','','b3','','',''], ['','','','','']]

for mysublist in data:
    while (mysublist[-1].rstrip() == "" and len(mysublist) > 1):
        del mysublist[-1]
```

For every sublist in data remove the last item if item is empty and if item is not the only* item.
Keep on doing it if there are still empty items at the end of a sublist.

(* the questioner: if all the elements are empty strings, only one empty string should remain)

Comment: Please add description about how the code works so that the questioner can understand the solution.

Comment: @Pardhu added description